# Why is my form not being saved to the database?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I'm trying to develop an e-commerce website using Django. I want to use Ajax to handle the view of my  checkout form after it has been submitted. After the form is submitted, I want it to go to :

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(next_page))+"?address_added=True")` , i.e http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?address_added=True

But for some reason, it is not going there. Rather it's being redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=W4iXFaxwpdtbZLyVI0ov8Uw7KWOM8Ix5GcOQ4k3Ve65KPkJwPUKyBVcE1IjL3GHa&address=123+Main+Street&address2=&state=MA&country=USA&zipcode=55525&phone=%28877%29+314-0742&billing=on`

As a result, the form data is also not getting saved. I was thinking if it were because of the new version of Django.

What I want to do is that after they submit the place order button, the form is going to be None, i.e disappear and then I would add a credit card form there for payment. But it is not happening. What is wrong here? How can I do this or is there a better way to do this?

My forms.py:

```
class UserAddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        fields = ["address", "address", "address2", "state", "country", "zipcode", "phone", "billing"]
```

My accounts.views.py:

```
def add_user_address(request):
    try:
        next_page = request.GET.get("next")
    except:
        next_page = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserAddressForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_address = form.save(commit=False)
            new_address.user = request.user
            new_address.save()
            if next_page is not None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(next_page))+"?address_added=True")
        else:
            raise Http404
    else:
        raise Http404
```

My orders.views.py:

```
@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        the_id = None
        return redirect(reverse("myshop-home"))

    try:
        new_order = Order.objects.get(cart=cart)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        new_order = Order(cart=cart)
        new_order.cart = cart
        new_order.user = request.user
        new_order.order_id = id_generator()
        new_order.save()
    except:
        return redirect(reverse("cart"))


    try:
        address_added = request.GET.get("address_added")
    except:
        address_added = None 

    if address_added is None:
        address_form = UserAddressForm()
    else:
        address_form = None

    if new_order.status == "Finished":
        #cart.delete()
        del request.session['cart_id']
        del request.session['items_total']
        return redirect(reverse("cart"))


    context = {"address_form": address_form, "cart": cart}
    template = "orders/checkout.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

My urls.py:

```
path('ajax/add_user_address', accounts_views.add_user_address, name='ajax_add_user_address'),
```

My checkout.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'ajax_add_user_address' %}?redirect=checkout">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">   
        {{ address_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Place Order</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Wilful and time-wasting self duplicate: [Why is my form not being saved to my Django database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317107/why-is-my-form-not-being-saved-to-my-django-database)

Comment: This question appears in a sequence of 11 questions from the same author on the same, or nearly the same topic. Many of these are copy-paste duplicate of each other, and will serve to waste the time of helpful readers who have not checked how many times the question has been re-asked.